# Is Erlang's security via cookies enough?

Tags: security, cookies, erlang, distributed-computing, erlang-otp

A thing concerning the security of Erlang's "secret cookie" mechanism.

1. Is that mechanism vulnerable in any way?
2. In case it is prone to unintended penetration should that be a concern?
3. What is your practice for making your Erlang nodes and their communication more secure?

Comment: I recommend you to consider using SSL http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/ssl/ssl_distribution.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Erlang's cookies are for topology, not for security.

In addition to the comment about ssl distribution, you should use all of the other mechanisms to secure your application that you would use in another environment.

Comment: This is definitely the case, keep your **ALL** erlang nodes securely protected behind a good firewall!

Comment: it's written in the documentation that erlang cookie is shared secret between the nodes. Does it mean, that rogue node having these cookie and nodes' ips can get access to data in the nodes?